# Opencart 3 на странице оформления заказа в последнем шаге добавить свою стоимость к массиву total?

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Последний шаг "подтверждение заказа", тут выводится перечень товаров из корзины с их названием, моделью, ценой... А также выводится `Итого`. Вот суть в том, что мне надо `к итого добавить свою цену`, которая уже содержится в переменной. Где находится файл, отвечающий за `total`? И вообще отдельный ли файл отвечает за total именно в `confirm.php/twig`?

Comment: @Skeggi код чего? Того файла, про который я спрашивал где он находится? Или про что Вы?

Comment: Простите, был невнимателен